# How to filter Bulk register IEntityTypeConfiguration<> by DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have multiple DbContext files within the application (multiple databases as well). I would like to filter IEntityTypeConfiguration registration by relevant DbContext.

e.g. I don't want any Account entity references in FirstDbContext or Customer ref. in SecondDbContext.

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfigurationsfromassembly?view=efcore-3.1), I should be able to pass a filter as a second parameter.

How do I go about here?

```
public class FirstDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public FirstDbContext (DbContextOptions<FirstDbContext > options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {            
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class SecondDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts{ get; set; }
    public SecondDbContext (DbContextOptions<SecondDbContext > options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {            
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

       // more options here
    }
}

public class AccountConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

       // more options here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ModelBuilder` should have already discovered your DbSet's at the start of `OnModelCreating`. So you should be able to filter the assembly types by their `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementation.

```cs
var types = modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Select(t => t.ClrType)
    .ToHashSet();

modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), 
    t => t.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>) 
            && types.Contains(i.GenericTypeArguments[0]))
    );
```

Though you might want a different solution to avoid the performance penalty of scanning the assembly multiple times.

Comment: Actually ModelBuilder does not discover dbset's according to the DbContext. e.g. when I run migration both Dbs contains Account and Customer. how do I overcome this?

Comment: A DbContext should represent a self contained schema. If your classes have properties that look like navigations, then they will also be discovered.  It sounds like you actually want one DbContext *implementation*, though you can access that through multiple interfaces with a sub-set of `DbSet` properties.

Comment: @ecasper Entity type discovery and inclusion in the model is explained in, well, [Including types in the model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model) section of the official EF Core documentation. The question you've asked (and have been answered here) eliminates just one of the indirect ways of including entity. SO rule is single question per post.  If you have different problem, then post another question and make sure to formulate the real issue rather than [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)